# Yii2 - data not saved in db even if condition satisfied, nothing in the log as well

Tags: php, yii2

here is my code, I am missing something obvious, but not able to figure out:

```
public function actionCheckout()
    {        
       $model = new User;
     //  $userProfile = UserProfile::find(['user_id'=>$model->id])->One();
       $userProfile = new UserProfile;
       $cartItems = $this->cart->getItems();

        if (Yii::$app->request->post())  {
            $cart = (array_merge(...$_SESSION['primary-cart']));         
            if($_POST['account-option']=="on"){
             //   echo "true";exit;
                $userProfile->first_name = $_POST['User']['first_name'];
                $userProfile->last_name = $_POST['User']['last_name'];
                $userProfile->phone = $_POST['User']['phone'];
                $userProfile->email = $_POST['User']['email'];
                $userProfile->address1 = $_POST['UserProfile']['address1'];
              //  $userProfile->address2 = $_POST['UserProfile']['address2'];
                $userProfile->city = $_POST['UserProfile']['city'];
                $userProfile->state = $_POST['UserProfile']['state'];
                $userProfile->Country = $_POST['User']['Country'];
                $userProfile->pincode = $_POST['UserProfile']['pincode'];
                $userProfile->save();
            }

            $params=[
                'id'=>$cart['productId'],               
                'amount'=> $cart['price'],
                'productinfo' => $cart['title'],                
                'firstname' => $_POST['User']['first_name'],
                'email' => $_POST['User']['email'],
                'phone' => $_POST['User']['phone']
            ];
            Yii::$app->Payu->PayuCheckout($params);

        }
        return $this->render('checkout',['model'=>$model,'userProfile' =>$userProfile,'cartItems' => $cartItems]);

    }
```

I am getting redirected to payU correctly, without any issue, but data is not saved to userProfile also nothing in the log as well.

Comment: Try with ```false``` in $userProfile->save(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var_dump($userProfile->getErrors())
```

right after saving it to see if there are any errors related to the model fields.

Comment: Thanks. there is a userid field, which is mandatory, your suggestion help me find it.